# shipping[].locationGroupName in Google Content API for .Net

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Does the current .Net Content API library (1.8.1.60) not support the locationGroupName property for ProductShipping?

The API documentation shows this as a property, but I don't seem to be able to find it in the latest class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you actually need to install this package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.ShoppingContent.v2/ 
and NOT this one:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Content.v2/